# Headers in CodeBlocks dosen't work for FriendlyARM

Tags: linux, arm, codeblocks

```
#include "linux/fs.h"
#include "linux/cdev.h"
#include "linux/module.h"
#include "linux/kernel.h"
#include "linux/device.h"
#include "asm/uaccess.h"
#include "asm/io.h"
#include "linux/slab.h"
```

I have a problem in codeblocks and FriendlyARM

I've install all headers using the comand

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Version: linux-headers-4.15.0-29

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X7rJ.png)I've configured the program in Compiler/Search Directories:

**/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29/include**

**/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include**

But when I will compile the aplication, CodeBlocks shows the error "No Such file or directory" in 
So I will configure this header then CodeBlocks shows other error and stay in infinite loop of errors in other headers.

How I do to CodeBlocks recognize all headers?

Comment: are you on the arm target you are compiling for or are you cross compiling?

Comment: Hei. Thanks!
I am using cross compiler form FriendlyARM. 
-->  arm-linux-gcc-4.5.1-v6-vfp-20120301

Comment: well then you certainly dont want to use the hosts header files assuming it is not also a FriendlyARM